# On Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, cauchy-sequences

I would consider this a soft question because I am seeking some insight on how to work with Cauchy sequences by using the Cauchy criterion for convergence.

To my understanding, the definition is given $\epsilon > 0$, there are sequences $a_n$ and $a_m > N$ such that, for $m>n >>N$, $|a_m - a_n| \approx_{\epsilon} N$. I have seen that my professor usually takes the differences between successive terms and forms a telescoping series in order to find the convergence. I am curious if there are other ways to approach such a problem without using a telescoping series. That is, are there other ways to find the convergence of a Cauchy sequence, and if so, what are they?

Thanks in advance for any input in this discussion.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is only one sequence in the definition. Let the sequence be $\{a_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. The definition is: for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n, m > N$ implies $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Also, if you are working on $\mathbb{R}$, then Cauchy sequences are equivalent to convergent sequences.

Comment: Yes, working in $\mathbb{R}$, sorry about that.

Comment: @ Jamil: If you want to show that any cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ converges, then you can apply nested interval theorem to prove that. Also, this is a standard result as $\mathbb R$ is complete.

Comment: @ Jamil: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5gVTCm-P14

Comment: @ jamil: The above link may be of some use.

Comment: To prove the Cauchy sequence $\{a_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are convergent, here is the proof sketch that I am familiar with: Show Cauchy sequences are bounded (just choose $\epsilon = 1$ so that all but finite terms are within a distance of max $1$ with each other). Then there exists a convergent subsequence $\{a_{k_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ which, say, converges to $L$ (well known theorem). Then using definition show that $\{a_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $L$ in the following way:

Comment: continued .....
Obviously, you can make $\{a_{k_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ close to $L$. For all terms not in $\{a_{k_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, use Cauchy to show they are close to $\{a_{k_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ which in turn is close to $L$.